# ajax update php variable from input box without submitting

Tags: php, ajax, variables, inputbox

So i am trying to type something in input box which i want to be dynamically stored in a variable. And then there is a hyperlink next to a table of records which will take this variable(.php?S=$inputboxvariable) and go to next php page which will execute a sql statement using this variable's value.

I do not want for submission , _GET or _POST or even SESSION variable in this.

Please help. I know coding would help but i dont know how, just a basic code would suffice.

Thanks

Comment: There is no way to do this without coding.

Comment: I think you are mistaking SO for rent-a-coder.

Comment: @thatidiotguy i know this requires coding thats what i am asking for.

Comment: @Petra i cant afford a coder thats why i asked for help. Thanks

Comment: @user1467788 sessions will do the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I get what your asking for now. The javascript below will make a call from your page to an external script (ajax/myscripthere.php) which will handle the SQL.

In the php script, we simply handle our SQL like we normally would if this was not an AJAX call.

Please accept answer if this is correct to your expectations :)

javascript:

```
<script>
    var xmlHttpReq = false;

    // Set ID Equal to your input box ID
    input_box_value = document.getElementById("inputboxvariable").value;

    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        self.xmlHttpReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if(window.ActiveXObject) {
        self.xmlHttpReq = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    // Set filename equal to your PHP script
    self.xmlHttpReq.open('POST', "ajax/myscripthere.php", true);

    self.xmlHttpReq.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(self.xmlHttpReq.readyState == 4)
        {
            // Update is complete
        }
    };

    self.xmlHttpReq.send("value="+input_box_value);
</script>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['value']))
{
    $conn = new mysqli("host", "username", "password", "db_name")
                 or die ('Error: '.mysqli_connect__error());

    // Make Correct SQL Query (i dont know your DB)
    $query = "UPDATE table_name SET col=".$_POST['value']." WHERE xxxxxx;";

    $result = @$conn->query($query);

    $conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont want to use get, post, or session to pass the variable but your example uses this:

```
(.php?S=$inputboxvariable)
```

Which would be passing the variable using GET.

If you are truely trying to avoid using these,

1. Use a database to store the data.
2. Use a file to store the data.

Maybe you could tell me why you are avoiding get, post, or session variables and I will understand better what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: but i am not using get on the main page, its the secondry page which use get to grab value of S. my concern is how to post it using ajax

Comment: so basically, the hyperlink on the main page will post the variable and take you to the next page?

Comment: alright, well I dont quite understand why you will not use get or post for this. But since this is what you asked for, I will try. I am assuming that you are avoiding post and get because you dont want to use a form/submit button for some reason?

Comment: Yes the php page is table retrieved from database so there is no form just a table and i am adding a field at the end which will update that row in database using the variable in put in one input box. i hope i have explained well.

Comment: Oh wait, so your wanted to update that value in the database? or are you trying to pass a variable from one page to another?

Comment: Yes trevor i am grabing value from inputbox and updating the hyperlink dynamically so when i click on hyperlink it just passes the variable without any submit.

Comment: refer to my new answer for code :)

Comment: Sorry trevor but i wasnt able to explain my  problem properly. i want to add picture but it wont let me

Comment: ahha whoah dude wheres a picture coming from? we started with a hyperlink moving a variable to the next page, then we had a database that needed to be updated, now a picture? Hmm..  think clearly about what you need and I will do my best. But be sure to be very clear because I am really having trouble figuring out what you are even trying to do...

Comment: omg sorry i meant i cannot add picture in my question because of my reputation which would help me explain my problem. I do not want to add picture to database

Comment: Ohh haha no problem, that just threw me off for a second :P Hmm would you like to move this to email (remove spaces)? trevor . kavanaugh @ gmail.com